# Inner join multiple entries in table comparison

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT produkte_eintraege.id, produkte_eintraege.hersteller, produkte_eintraege.titel, produkte_eintraege.img_url 
  FROM produkte_eintraege JOIN produkte_eigenschaften 
    ON produkte_eintraege.id = produkte_eigenschaften.produkte_eintraege_id 
 WHERE (produkte_eigenschaften.eigenschaften_merkmale_id = 1 
    OR produkte_eigenschaften.eigenschaften_merkmale_id = 2) 
   AND (produkte_eigenschaften.eigenschaften_merkmale_id = 3) 
 ORDER by hits DESC
```

Result = empty

```
SELECT produkte_eintraege.id, produkte_eintraege.hersteller, produkte_eintraege.titel, produkte_eintraege.img_url 
  FROM produkte_eintraege JOIN produkte_eigenschaften 
    ON produkte_eintraege.id = produkte_eigenschaften.produkte_eintraege_id 
 WHERE (produkte_eigenschaften.eigenschaften_merkmale_id = 1 
    OR produkte_eigenschaften.eigenschaften_merkmale_id = 2) 
 ORDER by hits DESC
```

Result = works

Whats wrong in this part?:

```
AND (produkte_eigenschaften.eigenschaften_merkmale_id = 3)
```

Here is the table:

```
INSERT INTO `produkte_eigenschaften` (`produkte_eintraege_id`, `eigenschaften_merkmale_id`)
VALUES (1, 2), (7, 1), (1, 3);
```

That means that one product has multiple entries in this table.

Comment: It is safe to assume that these querys will run on large datasets.. because produkteigenschaften (German) is "product features: in english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account your comments to Walter's answer, which you should've put in your question in the first place, to achieve your goal you have to `GROUP BY` product id and put your conditions in `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT produkte_eintraege_id 
  FROM produkte_eigenschaften
-- WHERE eigenschaften_merkmale_id IN(1, 2, 3)
 GROUP BY produkte_eintraege_id
HAVING MAX(eigenschaften_merkmale_id IN (1, 2)) = 1
   AND MAX(eigenschaften_merkmale_id = 3) = 1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3f37/2)** demo

Then you can `JOIN` back to `produkte_eintraege`

```
SELECT e.id, e.hersteller, e.titel, e.img_url
  FROM
(
    SELECT produkte_eintraege_id 
      FROM produkte_eigenschaften
    -- WHERE eigenschaften_merkmale_id IN(1, 2, 3)
     GROUP BY produkte_eintraege_id
    HAVING MAX(eigenschaften_merkmale_id IN (1, 2)) = 1
       AND MAX(eigenschaften_merkmale_id = 3) = 1
) q JOIN produkte_eintraege e
    ON q.produkte_eintraege_id = e.id
  ORDER BY hits DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

In your query you have

```
WHERE (produkte_eigenschaften.eigenschaften_merkmale_id = 1 OR produkte_eigenschaften.eigenschaften_merkmale_id = 2) 
AND (produkte_eigenschaften.eigenschaften_merkmale_id = 3) ORDER by hits DESC
```

To paraphrase the query you are saying

```
SELECT * 
FROM a join b 
WHERE (a.id=1 OR a.id=2) AND (a.ID=3)
```

A value cannot equal both 2 and three.

**SOLUTIONS**:There are two solutions that may solve your problem:

```
SELECT pe.id, pe.hersteller, pe.titel, pe.img_url 
FROM produkte_eintraege pe JOIN produkte_eigenschaften pe2 ON pe.id = pe2.produkte_eintraege_id 
WHERE (pe2.eigenschaften_merkmale_id = 1 
  OR pe2.eigenschaften_merkmale_id = 2 
  OR pe2.eigenschaften_merkmale_id = 3) ORDER by hits DESC
```

Or you can just use `IN`

```
SELECT pe.id, pe.hersteller, pe.titel, pe.img_url FROM produkte_eintraege pe JOIN produkte_eigenschaften pe2 ON pe.id = pe2.produkte_eintraege_id 
WHERE pe2.eigenschaften_merkmale_id IN (1,2,3) ORDER by hits DESC
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Not complete that what i need. pe2.eigenschaften_merkmale_id is like a filter. In this example it doesn't matter if pe2.eigenschaften_merkmale_id = 1 or OR pe2.eigenschaften_merkmale_id = 2, but OR pe2.eigenschaften_merkmale_id must be 3.

Comment: i want to get all products that height is 5cm or 10cm but only width of 5 cm

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to have a product whose Merkmale_id is both 2 and 3, no matter what data you put in. Do you mean OR instead of AND?

Comment: eigenschaften_merkmale_id: ID1 = height 5cm, ID2 = height 10cm, ID3 = width = 5cm, ID4 = 10 cm. One product (produkt_eintrage_id) is a single product which has different properties (eigenschaften_merkmale_id). So i want to get the produkt_eintrage_id of the product, that height is 5cm and width 10 cm for example

Comment: but in this example a second filter is set, so i want to get all products that height is 5cm, and 10cm but only width of 5 cm.

Comment: so i have first OR and then AND

Comment: The height is either 5cm or it is 10cm, or it is some other value, or the value is not provided.   The height cannot be 5cm and 10cm.